# Эквивалент MySQL INSERT IGNORE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Поставили задачу перенести проект с СУБД MySQL на Oracle. С Ораклом не знаком, изучаю в процессе.

Является ли хорошим тоном обрабатывать ошибки дублирования записей через:

```
EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
```

Или правильнее будет использовать `MERGE`?

Comment: merge  хороший выбор.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Является ли хорошим тоном обрабатывать ошибки дублирования записей через EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX или правильнее будет использовать MERGE?

Xорошим тоном является предварительный анализ данных и принятие на его основе решения.

- сколько строк данных для вставки ожидается
- отношение кол-ва дубликатов и новых строк
- источник данных от стороннего поставщика и непредсказуем

**Сравнение возможных решений**

Отлавливать исключения с `EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` в `FOR ... LOOP` или триггере несомненно не лучший выбор, чем явная проверка данных на наличие дубликатов до вставки.
Поэтому его далее не рассматриваю.

Допустим уже есть полмилиона строк и источник данных с милионом строк, из которых половина новых записей. Следует учесть, что изменение этого соотношения может значительно повлиять на результат. Для сравнения взял также [альтернативный ответ от @volkovirus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1068533/217579).

```sql
create table t1 as
    select rownum id, 'memo '||rownum memo
    from dual connect by level <= 5e5;

create or replace view source as 
    select rownum id, 'memo '||rownum memo
    from dual connect by level <= 1e6; 

alter table t1 add constraint pk_t1 primary key (id);     
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log (dml_table_name => 't1')
```

Сравнение времени выполнения:

```sql
declare 
    n number; 
begin
    --#1 not exists
    n := dbms_utility.get_time; 
    insert into t1 select * from select * from source s
    where not exists (select 1 from t1 t where t.id = s.id);
    dbms_output.put_line ('not exists elapsed='||(dbms_utility.get_time - n)/100||' ('||sql%rowcount||' rows)');
    rollback;

    --#2 merge
    n := dbms_utility.get_time; 
    merge into t1 t using source s on (s.id = t.id)
    when not matched then insert values (s.id, s.memo);
    dbms_output.put_line ('merge      elapsed='||(dbms_utility.get_time - n)/100||' ('||sql%rowcount||' rows)');
    rollback;

    --#3 log errors 
    n := dbms_utility.get_time; 
    insert into t1 select * from source s
    log errors reject limit unlimited;
    dbms_output.put_line ('w/ errlog  elapsed='||(dbms_utility.get_time - n)/100||' ('||sql%rowcount||' rows)');
    rollback;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```sql
Elapsed: 00:10:27.073

not exists elapsed=7,97 (500000 rows)
merge      elapsed=7,76 (500000 rows)
w/ errlog  elapsed=609,96 (500000 rows)
```

Выводы:

- если обновление/удаление старых записей не нужно,
  то проверки `#1 not exists` будет вполне достаточно
- если нужно обновление/удаление старых записей,
  то однозначно `#2 MERGE`
- если надо сразу протоколировать ошибки с выполнением по ним каких-либо действий,
  то `#3 log errors` будет уместным решением

Comment: Спасибо. Merge подошел мне больше всего

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от того, что вы хотите в итоге. `MERGE` в вашем случае может обновлять запись по сопоставляемым полям.

Также можно не генерировать `еxception`, а выкидывать все строки с ошибкой вставки в таблицу лога, которую вы в дальнейшем будете анализировать и принимать решение:

Создаём таблицу логов ошибок для таблицы:

```
begin
  dbms_errlog.create_error_log (dml_table_name => 'table1');
end;
```

Далее выполняем вставку в саму `table1`:

```
insert into table1
select *
from source_table
log errors into err$_table1 ('INSERT') reject limit unlimited;
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно оставить вставку как есть, и добавить подсказку [IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-20390275-91A7-49DC-AAD1-A1FE943A4F75).

В документации замечено, что для этой подсказки делается исключение из общего правила - избегать применение подсказок в продуктивной среде:

> **Note:** The `CHANGE_DUPKEY_ERROR_INDEX`, `IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX`, and `RETRY_ON_ROW_CHANGE` hints are unlike other hints in that they have a semantic effect.
> The general philosophy explained in Hints does not apply for these three hints.

```
create table tab (a number unique);
/
Table TAB created.

insert into tab
select 1 from dual union all
select 1 from dual
/
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DB.SYS_C0012764) violated

insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index (tab (a)) */ into tab
select 1 from dual union all
select 1 from dual
/

1 row inserted.
```